# Predictive model to predict probability of device failue

Tags: probability

I need to build a predictive model to predict probability of device failure. I have data in below format

```
Date        Device Failure Attribute1  Attribute2
01-Jan-18    A      0       1423        1234
02-Jan-18    A      0       1123        1290
03-Jan-18    A      1       1230        1260
01-Jan-18    B      0       981         810
02-Jan-18    B      0       970         785
03-Jan-18    B      0       933         750
03-Jan-18    B      0       933         750
04-Jan-18    B      1       913         730
05-Jan-18    B      0       933         810
06-Jan-18    B      0       940         825
07-Jan-18    B      0       952         765
08-Jan-18    B      0       963         752
09-Jan-18    B      0       943         738
10-Jan-18    B      1       923         728
```

`
I have some more attributes but for simplicity I put 2 attributes & failure=1 means device failed
Can you suggest me how should I proceed?

Comment: Weibull? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

Comment: But how can I use those attributes in model?

Comment: I do not understand your data. And it was a suggestion, because Weibull is used in  reliability engineering and failure analysis.